# How to check if a packet hits tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

Is it possible to check if any request has hit the Tomcat? something similar to access.log of Apache server. I am using Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache Tomcat provides the configuration directory **conf**, that contains the file **server.xml**. At the bottom of this file, a line that includes the adjustments valve, called **AccessLogValve** must be un-commented and changed.

The default valve parameters and patterns can easily be modified, either through an editor, or by an application. This is a reasonably detailed log file that can be used for access metrics:

```
<Valve
   className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve."
   directory="logs"
   prefix="sitename_acc."
   suffix=".log"
   pattern='%a %A %b %B %h %l %m %p %q %u %t "%r" %s %U %D %S'
   resolveHosts="false"
   rotatable="true"
   fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
/>
```

You can even have multiple tomcat instances running at the same time, each with it's own access log file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, look at [The stuff here under access valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve)

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for debugging a filter defined in `web.xml` might be useful:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.example.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In your filter implementation `MyFilter` you have access to `ServletRequest` and can e.g. access session variables:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter
{
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                       FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```